# Individual cell editing in jqgrid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jqgrid-php

I am using jqgrid to display data, and am having an issue which is making me think there is a limit to what jqgrid can do. I am hoping someone has an answer that allows me to keep using jqgrid which works fine and is in use throughout the site.

I would like the ability to allow a dropdown to appear and allow editing of a cell if a user clicks on it, but also invoke a js popup if the user clicks in the same row on another column. Currently we have it set up so that when a user clicks anywhere in the row they get the js popup, but there is one field the client wants to be able to edit with a simple dropdown, while keeping the js popup invoked when the user clicks on other cells in that row

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [viewing the demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Specifically, look at Row Editing -> Input types (the tree on the left-hand-side).

This will point you in the direction of in-cell editing.

[This entry in the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editable) will help in understanding how to structure your column model with callbacks to fire.

The js popup logic you mentioned is I think do-able but will require wiring a click event for the duration of editing, only.

I highly recommend going through the demos which are very helpful.

Good luck!

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in jqGrid.